# Built-in screenshot tool does not have screencast button?

Tags: gnome, xorg

I am running Ubuntu 22.10 with all of the latest updates.
As far as I remember, the screenshot tool should now have a second icon which allows you to also make recordings as shown below.

[image: gnome screenshot/screencast screenshot]

For some mysterious reason, this option is not even showing for me -- I only have the screenshot option (screen recording is completely missing).

Am I missing a package that provides this? I am currently running on xorg, does it perhaps only work on wayland?

I have already installed `gstreamer` as per [the documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c#install-gstreamer-on-ubuntu-or-debian)

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

Comment: Mine looks like the screenshot you posted. What kind of GPU do you have?

Comment: The title and the question do not match. The title says cast. Please correct.

Comment: @David the title is correct. The built-in screenshot tool (which is how it's called in ubuntu) does not have the "screencast" option. Both of these are part of the screenshot tool, are they not? :)

Comment: FWIW I managed to get it to work in a very dangerous way. Tried to remove gstreamer (don't do that!) which almost crashed my ubuntu. Anyway, after installing `gnome-session` again everything worked ang both the screenshot and screencast options were showing. I probably had a missing or corrupted dependency but I don't know which one.